# Redux + Hooks useDispatch() in useEffect calling action twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm beginner in redux & hooks. I am working on form handling and trying to call an action through `useDispatch` hooks but it is calling my action twice.

I'm referring [this](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-redux/) article.

Here is the example:

**useProfileForm.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchProfile } from '../../../redux/profile/profile.actions';

const useProfileForm = (callback) => {

    const profileData = useSelector(state =>
        state.profile.items        
    );

    let data;
    if (profileData.profile) {
        data = profileData.profile;
    }

    const [values, setValues] = useState(data);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchProfile());
    }, [dispatch]);

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        callback();
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        event.persist();
        setValues(values => ({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
    };

    return {
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        values,
    }
};

export default useProfileForm;
```

**Action**

```
export const FETCH_PROFILE_BEGIN = "FETCH_PROFILE_BEGIN";
export const FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS = "FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS";
export const FETCH_PROFILE_FAILURE = "FETCH_PROFILE_FAILURE";
export const ADD_PROFILE_DETAILS = "ADD_PROFILE_DETAILS";

function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

function getProfile() {
    return fetch("url")
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(res => res.json());
}

export function fetchProfile() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchProfileBegin());
        return getProfile().then(json => {
            dispatch(fetchProfileSuccess(json));
            return json;
        }).catch(error =>
            dispatch(fetchProfileFailure(error))
        );
    };
}

export const fetchProfileBegin = () => ({
    type: FETCH_PROFILE_BEGIN
});

export const fetchProfileSuccess = profile => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
        payload: { profile }
    }
};

export const fetchProfileFailure = error => ({
    type: FETCH_PROFILE_FAILURE,
    payload: { error }
});

export const addProfileDetails = details => {
    return {
        type: ADD_PROFILE_DETAILS,
        payload: details
    }
};
```

**Reducer:**

```
    import { ADD_PROFILE_DETAILS, FETCH_PROFILE_BEGIN, FETCH_PROFILE_FAILURE, FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS } from './profile.actions';

    const INITIAL_STATE = {
        items: [],
        loading: false,
        error: null
    };

    const profileReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case ADD_PROFILE_DETAILS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    addProfileDetails: action.payload
                }
            case FETCH_PROFILE_BEGIN:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    loading: true,
                    error: null
                };

            case FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    loading: false,
                    items: action.payload.profile
                };

            case FETCH_PROFILE_FAILURE:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    loading: false,
                    error: action.payload.error,
                    items: []
                };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

    export default profileReducer;


**Component:**

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import useProfileForm from './useProfileForm';
import { addProfileDetails } from '../../../redux/profile/profile.actions';

const EducationalDetails = () => {

    const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useProfileForm(submitForm);

    console.log("values", values);


    function submitForm() {
        addProfileDetails(values);
    }

    if (values) {
        if (values.error) {
            return <div>Error! {values.error.message}</div>;
        }

        if (values.loading) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
    }

    return (
        <Card>
            ...some big html
        </Card>
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addProfileDetails: details => dispatch(details)
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(EducationalDetails);
```

Also when I'm passing data from `const [values, setValues] = useState(data);` useState to values then ideally I should receive that in component but I'm not getting as it is showing undefined.

```
const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useProfileForm(submitForm);
```

*values is undefined*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The twice dispatch of action is probably because you have used `React.StrictMode` in your react hierarchy.

According to the react docs, in order to [`detect unexpected sideEffects`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects), react invokes a certain functions twice such as

```
Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer
```

Now since react-redux is implemented on top of react APIs, actions are infact invoked twice

**Also when I'm passing data from const [values, setValues] = useState(data); useState to values then ideally I should receive that in component but I'm not getting as it is showing undefined.**

To answer this question, you must know that values is not the result coming from  the response of dispatch action from reducer but a state that is updated when handleChange is called so that is supposed to remain unaffected by the action

I think you mean to expose the redux data from `useProfileForm` which forgot to do

```
const useProfileForm = (callback) => {

    const profileData = useSelector(state =>
        state.profile.items        
    );

    let data;
    if (profileData.profile) {
        data = profileData.profile;
    }

    const [values, setValues] = useState(data);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchProfile());
    }, [dispatch]);

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        callback();
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        event.persist();
        setValues(values => ({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
    };

    return {
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        values,
        data // This is the data coming from redux store on FetchProfile and needs to logged
    }
};

export default useProfileForm;
```

You can use the data in your component like

```
const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit, data } = useProfileForm(submitForm);
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to receive the `data` in my component from userProfileForm? Or do I need to use `useState()` in component only?

Comment: `According to the react docs, in order to detect unexpected sideEffects, react invokes a certain functions twice such as` : Is this happening bcz I'm using hooks with redux or same would happen if I use mapStateToProps or mapStateToDispatch?

Comment: I updated my answer on how you will receive the data in component. Also the double invocation is because of React.StrictMode somewhere in hierarchy. It does't matter if you use hoooks or classs components. However you should be worried about double invocation. If at all it will help you figure out issues in your app. Also please read the docs on this for more details. I have added the link in the post

Comment: I have already tried `const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit, data } = useProfileForm(submitForm);` but still I'm getting values and data as `undefined`

Comment: Yeah sorry there was some mistake while passing object. Now its working. Thanks

Comment: :-) Glad you figured out. I was about to take a look :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to overcome this issue. I have researched this issue and find a solution to remove **React.StrictMode** from the root file in react like

```
root.render(
   <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
   </React.StrictMode>
);
```

to like this

```
root.render(<App />);
```

But **React.StrictMode** mode is good for capturing warnings and issue in code. so I have found another way to fix this issue that we have to use async call in useEffect to avoid double api call. So I used api call in useEffect like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
    let getData = setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(fetchProfile());
      }, 0)
    return () => clearTimeout(getData)
  },[])
```

Or you can use promise to create an async call